# Is it possible to make a V-causative-te construction?

Tags: て-form, causation

According to Genki II, "any causative verb can be interpreted either with the "*make* somebody do" reading or the "*let* somebody do" reading".

In English, it's not uncommon to hear a construction such as "Let it drop" or "Make him do it". So are there constructions such as 「落ちさせて」?

Comment: Please write answers in the answer box :-)

Comment: Do you have a particular situation/context in mind to use 「落ちさせて」 in?  I ask because a phrase being grammatical and it being natural-sounding are two separate things.

Comment: 落ちさす is unnatural but causative verb +て is common. For example, 私は子供を学校に行かせてから、掃除した.

Comment: @YuuichiTam I think the OP is asking about て as an imperative form rather than the example above.

Comment: @user3856370 て don't have an imperative form because it's a postpositional particle but the verbal auxiliary of  causative has the form like せろ、せよ、させよ、させろ.

Comment: Well, i think what i meant by "Let it drop" is a bit ambiguous unfortunately, it's a line to song. I suppose the imagery it creates in context is more like holding onto something with all your might but finally letting your muscles relax and letting "it" drop, and letting the chaos of whatever "dropping it" might be just come. 

But a meaning like this is understandably hard to translate. I think I was struck by the grammatical constuction of it in English and wondered if it existed in Japanese. Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what “causative verb” means in your book, but judging from the 落ちさせる example, I assume that it means verbs with -せる/させる suffix such as 遊ばせる and 片付けさせる.  (使役動詞 in Japanese usually means a different form: it means verbs such as 落ちさす, 遊ばす, and 片付けさす.)

Then you can just use them in the imperative form with -て.  A child may say to their parents:

> 宿題が終わったらテレビゲームで遊ばせて。  Let me play a video game after I finish homework.

If a father always cleans his child’s room, a mother may say to him:

> 遥に自分で片付けさせて。  Make Haruka clean up her own room.

“Let it drop.” in English *would* be 落ちさせて in Japanese if we only considered grammar, but we just do not say it that way.  If “let it drop” means something like “do not worry about it,” it is usually just 気にしないで or 放っておいて.